# ImageField not uploading my pic in template

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with uploading an image to my template. Code below, project-tree screen too. If you will need anything to help me, write pls.

**project-tree screen**

[image]

(model) Here comes particular model with which I got the problem.

```
class WorkingPlace(models.Model):
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
from_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
till_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default='now')

def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name
```

(view)

```
def main_view(request):
form = ContactMe(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print('saved')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('CV/base.html')
else:
    form = ContactMe()
    print('unsaved')

hobbies_and_interests = HobbiesAndInterest.objects.all()
personal_features = PersonalFeature.objects.all()
skills = Skill.objects.all()
letter = Letter.objects.get(id=1)
working_places = WorkingPlace.objects.all()
activities = Activity.objects.all()
return render(request, 'CV/base.html', {
        'form': form,
        'hobbies_and_interests': hobbies_and_interests,
        'personal_features': personal_features,
        'skills': skills,
        'letter': letter,
        'working_places': working_places,
        'activities': activities
    })
```

(settings) Static and Media settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "CV/../CV/../static"),

]

STATIC_ROOT = 'WebCVDjangoI'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', "media")
```

(template) Problem part of the template.

```
{% for place in working_places %}
        <div class="row work-block">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 3em;"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11 flex-around">

                <img src="{{ place.logo.url }}" class="img-respomsive visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block" style="width: 30%">
                {{ place.logo.url }}
                <!--Mobile-->
                <img src="{{ place.logo }}" class="img-respomsive visible-xs-block" style="width: 50%">
                <!--end-->

                <div style="width: 30%" class="text-center visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block">
                    <h4>
                        <span class="blue" style="color: dodgerblue"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                       {{ place.location }}
                    </h4>
                    <span style="text-decoration: underline">{{ place.from_date }} - {{ place.till_date }}</span><br>
                 </div>
                <div style="width: 30%" class="visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block">
                    <span class="blue"><h4>Activity:</h4></span>
                    <ul>
                        {% for activity in activities %}
                            {% if activity.working_place == place %}
                                <li>{{ activity.activity }}</li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--Mobile-->
                <div style="width: auto" class="visible-xs-block">
                    <h4>
                        <span class="blue" style="color: dodgerblue"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        {{ place.location }}
                    </h4>
                    <span style="text-decoration: underline">{{ place.from_date }} - {{ place.till_date }}</span><br>
                    <span class="blue"><h4>Activity:</h4></span>
                    <ul>
                        {% for activity in activities %}
                            {% if activity.working_place == place %}
                                <li>{{ activity.activity }}</li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                <!--end-->
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Help to make images from Admin display in the template.

Also, here is my project tree:

Comment: uploading is kind of confusing word. Are you uploading in the image from django admin interface, and trying to display in template and it is not working ?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I meant

Comment: try adding forward slash upload_to='img/'

Comment: Tried this right now. Doesn't help(